# Unable to send messages from the pc back to the node on Android phone

Tags: ros, script, roscore, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been using the android package ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/android ) which uses the SL4A scripting environment on the android phone to execute scripts. The package allows successful connection with the roscore running on the host pc.

The test node created by the package can publish onto topics and the computer can receive it. However, the package cannot receive messages which are published onto topics by the computer.

A look at the problem showed that if you ran a second script to create another test node that publishes onto the topic the first test node is subscribed to, the first test node responds correctly. Therefore, I guess it is the problem with the data not being transferred successfully back to the script.

Please advise on how I can possibly configure this.

Soe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10553/unable-to-send-messages-from-the-pc-back-to-the-node-on-android-phone./) by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Soe, my bet is the problem is a networking issue.  Your computer is probably using a hostname that the phone cannot resolve.  If you set the ROS_IP on the computer or set up a DNS that the phone can use, you should be ok.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on 2011-07-11**:
The ROS concept was working very well so I thought the networking might need some changes to the configurations, but was not sure how to proceed. Thanks for the idea; I'll try it out.